# How can I change XSD Path in deployed SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, ssis

I am new to SSIS packages. I have an SSIS package Solution in my local machine. 
It has an XML Source component which uses an XSD file in my local machine.
When I deploy this on my SQL Server, How can I set the path to a new location on server ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the package to dynamically recreate the data flow according to the xsd or are you changing the location without changing the contents of the xsd file?

Comment: I want to  change XSD data type of one field from UnsignedByte to Integer. But the deployed SSIS package shows error "Data Type information on element has changed" 
I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the XSD path using a Configuration variable. In this case, whenever you will change the configuration it will pick the new path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this guide is what you're looking for:

http://fuzzy-group.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/ssis-create-dynamic-xsd-source-file-for.html

It allows you to store your xsd in a database where it is configurable, and then loads it dynamically at run time.

I'm not sure exactly how much of an xsd change this can handle, but I think this is the closest you can get without dynamically generating the whole package.